# SortExpression expression occurred while sorting by NULL data column

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, rdlc, sortexpression

In my database in the AccountNumber field have data with NULL data. In the RDLC reports, I got the following error while I'm sorting that filed.

```
The SortExpression expression for the text box ‘textbox1’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

And I think this error occurs because of `NULL` data. when it has data it is sorting properly.

Part of my RDLC XML as follows,

```
<Textbox Name="textbox1">
    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
    <UserSort>
        <SortExpression>=CLng(Fields!Account.Value)</SortExpression>
        <SortExpressionScope>table1_Group1</SortExpressionScope>
        <SortTarget>dsReportData</SortTarget>
    </UserSort>
    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
    <Paragraphs>
        <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                    <Value>=Parameters!AccountNumberDisplayText.Value</Value>
                    <MarkupType>HTML</MarkupType>
                    <Style>
                        <FontFamily>Verdana</FontFamily>
                        <FontSize>9pt</FontSize>
                        <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                        <Color>#000000</Color>
                    </Style>
                </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
            <Style />
        </Paragraph>
    </Paragraphs>
    <rd:DefaultName>textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
    <ZIndex>30</ZIndex>
    <Style>
        <Border>
            <Color>White</Color>
            <Style>Solid</Style>
        </Border>
        <TopBorder>
            <Color>White</Color>
        </TopBorder>
        <BottomBorder>
            <Color>White</Color>
        </BottomBorder>
        <LeftBorder>
            <Color>#eeeeeb</Color>
        </LeftBorder>
        <RightBorder>
            <Color>#eeeeeb</Color>
        </RightBorder>
        <BackgroundColor>#dcdcdc</BackgroundColor>
        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
    </Style>
</Textbox>
```

I saw in some reports Account filed as follows

```
<SortExpression>=Trim(Fields!Account.Value)</SortExpression>
```

and its working fine with NULL data, Therefore I tried to avoid this error by changing this (`<SortExpression>=CLng(Fields!Account.Value)</SortExpression>`) as above code

But it gave me another error

> The definition of the report 'F:....\ReportName.rdlc' is invalid.
>   The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this
>   version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been
>   created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content
>   that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services
>   schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target
>   namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition'
>   which cannot be upgraded.

Comment: Is the namespace attribute "rd" defined in the file?

Comment: @jdweng I'm not clear what you asking.So however this error occurred after I change `<SortExpression>=CLng(Fields!Account.Value)</SortExpression>` this XML line. I change it because of SortExpression error

Comment: My guess is the following line may be an issue with "rd" not being defined in the file :  <rd:DefaultName>textbox1</rd:DefaultName>  Does the textbox contain a string?

Comment: @jdweng As I mentioned in the question, this Account number filed with null data sorting fine in some reports, Can you please tell me have any possible way to add this `CLng` and `Trim` without editing XML file, I mean have any possible way to add it from the report design side without editing report XML?

Comment: If data is in the database that is not trimmed, then best thing is to fix the database.  Write a stored procedure and trims the fields in the database.  Then make sure in the future that all data going into database gets trimmed.

Comment: @jdweng Why `rdlc' is invalid` error occurs after I change XML code as `<SortExpression>=Trim(Fields!Account.Value)</SortExpression>` . And What is the difference between `CLng` and `Trim`.

Comment: 1) Clng : Convert to c-language.  2) Trim : Remove spaces at end of string.

Comment: The sort expression is shown on following webpage under "Examing the Sorting Workflow" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/paging-and-sorting/paging-and-sorting-report-data-cs